# Can SFP+ and RJ45 10Gb be bonded?

Tags: lag, bonding, aggregation

I'm looking at getting a QNAP TS-EC1680U-E3-4GE-R2 NAS. It ships with a dual port SFP+ PCIe card. I would also like to add in a dual port m.2 + 10Gb RJ45 combined card to use for SSD caching. I would also like to bond this extra 10Gb RJ45 port to the existing SFP+ ports with my Netgear XS728T to create a 3 way LACP LAG. Anyone know if this possible? Same speeds but different connections. Ta.

Answer (score 0):

LACP mandates that each slave is the same speed and duplex.

It doesn't matter what brand/model each slave is. They can be different.

However you should use the same hardware offloading features on each card.

For example, if one card supports LRO and one doesn't, then disable LRO on the bond and slaves.

Answer (score -1):

In theory yes, bond-members can even be different speeds.

In practice it totally depends on the OS and the drivers.
Ask QNAP tech-support. That is the only way to know for sure.

Comment: Already have done :) They said in theory it should work although the haven't tried it so couldn't confirm. I would like to know for sure before I drop my cash on it. Was hoping that someone here had. The OS would be QTS, the OS that ships with the QNAP NAS.

Your comment that bond-members can have different speeds interests me as it goes against everything I have read on the subject. In theory then I could add another 4x1Gb to the bond?

Comment: @ChrisBrearley I have personally setup a bond between 4x 1Gb/s (on-board NICs, Broadcom chipset if I remember correctly) and 2x 10 Gb/s (Intel dual-port card) on a HP Proliant DL380. Target switch was a Cisco 4900M with 1 Gb/s and 10 Gb/s line-cards. We didn't need that bandwidth, but I had the stuff available and just wanted to see if it could be done. That was on Centos Linux. So I know for a fact that it can work. How it works for you I can't say of course.

Comment: Thanks Tonny, that's good to know. I think I'll give that a shot as well. Not sure what I'll gain (if any) by adding another 4Gb to 30Gb but if the stuff is there then why not give it a go. Cheers.

Comment: @ChrisBrearley I seriously doubt you can gain any performance above 10 Gb/s. Limiting factor is going to be the NAS CPU and throughput to the disk-system.